# How to limit the size of figure+caption?

Tags: floats, adjustbox

I do have my figures (and tables) sometimes with several lines long caption. I am trying to fill out my pages optimally, so I put the payload content in a  \maxsizebox. In most cases it works fine, until a comment is too long, in which case part of the caption goes off-page. As I understand, I cannot place a floating object in a \maxsizebox.  Can I limit the height of image+caption somehow?

Comment: you would have a better chance of an answer if you showed a complete document that allowed peopel to see the problem and test possible answers.

Comment: You can put the image and caption inside a minipage, and the minipage inside \maxizebox, and a \maxsizebox inside a float.

Comment: @ John Kormylo I think my problem is that a caption must not be used outside a figure or table, which can float, and so cannot go into a \maxizebox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One could use `\newlength` and `\settowidth` instead of `\savebox`, but this is faster.  One could also set the `minipage` width to `\textwidth` instead of the image width.  The main difference is that this way a long caption will match the image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\savebox{\tempbox}{\includegraphics{example-image}}% get width of image
\centering\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{.2\textheight}{%
\begin{minipage}{\wd\tempbox}%
\usebox{\tempbox}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

[image: resizebox with caption]

Note, it is also possible to resize just the image so that the image plus caption fit into a given height.

```
\newcommand{\maxfigure}[3]% #1 = max height, #2 = image, #3 = caption
{\bgroup
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\caption{#3}\end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\ht0>#1\relax\errmessage{\string\maxfigure: caption too big}
  \else\centering\maxsizebox{\textwidth}{\dimexpr #1 - \ht0}{#2}\fi
  \par\box0
\egroup}
```

Comment: That last bit of code is *awesome*, thank you!  Note for `floatrow` users who want to use it: You need to put `\RawCaption` around the `\caption`, and you probably need to include `- \abovecaptionskip` in the `\dimexpr`.  (Maybe you need to account for `\abovecaptionskip` regardless of `floatrow`.)  Also, I put the `\label` in the `minipage` with the `\caption` and it seems to work.

Comment: I replaced `\textwidth` by `\columnwidth` in the final piece of code for it to work in a two-column IEEE template.

Comment: In addition, I had to subtract `\dp0` in addition to `\ht0`, see examples in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/596052/. By contrast, at least in IEEE document classes `\abovecaptionskip` is included in the `\caption` command, so it's measured by `\ht0+\dp0`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}` package for this, it automatically scales.

Or a less elegant but shorter manual solution is to use the `scale` option

```
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figure.png}
```

See related answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/488985/34958