# Caption outside document body

Tags: floats, body

I have an image in my document that I want to display as big as possible in landscape orientation but the whole figure (image AND caption) should be within the limits of the [body](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout).

I researched a lot how to define the size for the whole figure environment and the most suggested solution was to replace the figure by a minipage. However, I don't get the result I want to have.

MWE for the minipage approach:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, DIV=13, 12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{This is the Title}
\author{It's a Me, Mario!}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[6]

\begin{landscape}
    \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][t]{\linewidth}
        \centering     
        \noindent\includegraphics[height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{This is the long version of the description of the caption}
        \label{fig:flussdiagramm}    
    \end{minipage}
\end{landscape}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

But the problem stays the same: The caption is outside of the body. Here's what I mean:
[image]

The margin of the caption (red arrow) does not match the margin of the other pages (blue arrows).

I thought, that a minipage redefines the `\textheight` and `\linewidth` but it seems that this is not the case. Can anybody confirm this?

How can I make sure, that the caption is within the body/text area and the margins stay the same on each page?

Best,
Korbinian

Comment: if you have `\includegraphics[height=\textheight,` the image will be full height and not leave room for a caption

Comment: Is there an existing length for the height of the caption, so that I can substract it from the image's height? 

I saw some solutions where people calculate the height but is this really the easiest way/best practice for this?

Comment: no you can write a 20-line caption, so if you want that you would have to set the caption text in a box first and measure before setting the image

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

@Others: I did the calculation with Frank Mittelbach's answer (first code block) on this post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47185/261955

It worked for me. You can also keep the figure environment and don't need a minipage.

Comment: For the sake of completeness:

>I thought, that a minipage redefines the \textheight and \linewidth but it seems that this is not the case. 

Can anybody confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Carlisle wrote, the height of the caption has to be calculated during the compilation of the document to determine the height available for the image.

I used @Frank Mittelbach's answer on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47185/261955) for the calculation. This piece of code works well for me:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\graphht              % holds the height available for the image
\newcommand\calculategraphicstargetheight[1]{%    % pass the number of lines of the caption
     \setlength\graphht{\textheight 
                       -\parskip
                       -\abovecaptionskip -\belowcaptionskip
                       -(\baselineskip * #1)
                       }}
```

Use it like this:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \calculategraphicstargetheight{1}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \centering
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\graphht,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
        \captionof{figure}{This is the long version of the description of the caption}
        \label{fig:niceimage}
    \end{figure}
\end{landscape}
```

The result is as follows:

[image: The caption is no longer outside of the document's body]

Korbinian